# Malformed plain text after decipher using crypto-js package in typescript for the text encrypted using Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode

I am trying to decipher an encrypted text (which is created in java) using typescript and crypto-js package but the result is malformed .

Expected output: {"someKey": "someValue","someOtherKey":{"innerKey":"value"}}

Actual output:  {#qweqsu*3(zynmiss","someOtherKey":{"innerKey":"value"}}

Here is the java code used for encryption:

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getMD5(painTextKey), "AES"); 
byte[] iv = new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}; 
AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); 
Cipher encCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
Cipher decCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 

encCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec); 
decCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec); 

//Encryption
byte[] ciphertext = encCipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
String encryptedHex = byteToHex(ciphertext); 

//Decryption 
plaintext = new String(decCipher.doFinal(hexToByte(hexCipherText)),"UTF-8");
```

Here is my typescript implementation of the same :

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const SECRET = CryptoJS.MD5("45bd6682f7524e8aa7ce6c06de537a3d")
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);


function encrypt(plainText){
    var base64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, SECRET, {iv: iv ,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,keySize: 256}).toString();
    var parsedVal = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64);
    return parsedVal.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
}

function decrypt(cipherText){
   var parsedVal = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipherText);
   var bytesVal = parsedVal.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
   var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(bytesVal, SECRET, {iv: iv ,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,keySize: 256});
   return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypt)
}
```

Please let me know if my implementation is right and the cause of this problem .
Thanks!

Comment: In the NodeJS code a different IV is used. For converting a byte array to a `WordArray` s. [here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1) or use a CryptoJS [encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders), e.g. the `Hex` encoder. Note that a static IV is insecure as well as MD5 and a digest for key derivation.

Comment: Thanks , worked